# Parsing Yaml in Java

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, jackson-databind

I have the following `YAML` I want to parse using `Jackson` parser in Java.

```
android:
    "7.0":
        - nexus
        - S8
    "6.0":
        - s7
        - g5
ios:
    "10.0":
        - iphone 7
        - iphone 8
```

I created a created `class` which has `getter` and `setter` as `Java Object` for `android`. It works fine. But how do I do the same for `6.0` and `7.0? I'm using`Jackson` Parser

Comment: Have you searched for an example? First Google result - https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson

Comment: @DanW Yes, I used the exact same page as a reference. But I'm not sure how to get it working when there is numerics , For eg: `7.0`

Comment: @Damien-Amen: Just treat them as strings. Ignore that they happen to look like numbers. They're actually strings

Answer (score 6):

No idea whether Jackson supports that; here's a solution with plain SnakeYaml (I will never understand why people use Jackson for parsing YAML when all it does is basically take away the detailed configuration possible with SnakeYaml which it uses as backend):

```
class AndroidValues {
     // showing what needs to be done for "7.0". "8.0" works similarly.
     private List<String> v7_0;

     public List<String> getValuesFor7_0() {
         return v7_0;
     }

     public void setValuesFor7_0(List<String> value) {
         v7_0 = value;
     }
}

// ... in your loading code:

Constructor constructor = new Constructor(YourRoot.class);
TypeDescription androidDesc = new TypeDescription(AndroidValues.class);
androidDesc.substituteProperty("7.0", List.class, "getValuesFor7_0", "setValuesFor7_0");
androidDesc.putListPropertyType("7.0", String.class);
constructor.addTypeDescription(androidDesc);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);

// and then load the root type with it
```

**Note:** Code has not been tested.

Comment: I am fairly new to YAML world and have been evaluating the various offerings and Jackson indeed seems to use SnakeYaml under the hood - so I am asking the same question you are... why use Jackson YAML and not SnakeYaml directly?

Comment: @Volksman Jackson may already be in use for parsing JSON or XML, and so some might rather use something they are already using or are familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should try annotation `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`. I'll provide a short example below.

Sample YAML file:

```
---
"42": "some value"
```

Data transfer object class:

```
public class Entity {

    @JsonProperty("42")
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Parser:

```
public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        Entity entity = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/sample.yml"), Entity.class);
        System.out.println(entity.getValue());
    }

}
```

The console output should be: `some value`.

**P.S.** I tested it with the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```